# How can I make atom-beautify work with html in php file?

Tags: php, html, atom-editor, auto-indent, atom-beautify

I installed the atom-beautify package in my Atom Editor.

I open a file index.php

```
 <ul>
 <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
```

then I make the command "Beautify".

But my code still looks like this:

```
 <ul>
 <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
```

I expect the code to change to this:

```
 <ul>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried it with a "pure" PHP file? Could be the package doesn't recognize HTML in PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you ever tried keying "**beautify html**" in atom command line? (using **CMD+shift+P** in Atom to open command line) It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Taking 吳 品 儒 's answer further and making things easier, you can create a keybinding.

Open Atom >> File >> Settings >> Keybindings. 
There will be a leyend on top of the search bar that goes like this "***You can override these keybindings by copying and pasting them into your keymap file***", click on it, it should open a keymap.cson

Copy this code and paste it at the end of the file:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-n': 'atom-beautify:beautify-language-html'
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't.

You can, however, stick the HTML into a new tab, set the language as HTML, then beautify.
Simply paste it back over.

Comment: Wow, I can't imagine. Because in the Brackets Editor this works very well. I thought that the Atom Editor is at least as powerful as the Brackets Editor

Comment: Some things, unfortunately, aren't as powerful as Brackets. Some things are equal or better. 'tis the way it is of "rival" editors.

Comment: What means "rival"?

Comment: In competition with each other. More people using their product = more exposure.